# Network speed for a 1/10 Gigabit card

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet, netplan

I have a computer which has a "NetXtreme II BCM57800 1/10 Gigabit Ethernet" network card which I am trying to connect at 10 Gigabits/s but it is connecting at 1 Gigabits/s.  It is running Ubuntu 18.04.4.

On another computer with a different card which is advertised as "10 Gigabit Ethernet", I connected the cables, brought the link up, edited the Netplan YAML file with a static IP address and the connection worked from the beginning.  That is, with `ethtool`, I saw "Speed: 10000Mb/s".

Applying the same steps to that first computer gets me only "Speed: 1000Mb/s".  So, I'm wondering if I have to do something to "turn on" 10 Gigabit Ethernet?  That is, does the "1/10" in the name mean I need to do something explicitly.  When I run `ethtool`, I see the following:

```
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full
```

So, this isn't very encouraging.

On this computer, I'm connecting two ports, both of which have this problem.  So, unless I have two faulty cables, I'm thinking this cannot be a cable problem.  Also, it's the same 10 GBaseT switch that's connected to the other computer I mentioned earlier; so I think/hope it isn't a problem with the switch.

Anyway help would be appreciated!

Edit 1:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:0                       
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme II BCM57800 1/10 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: [...]
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bnx2x driverversion=1.712.30-0 duplex=full firmware=FFV14.05.01 bc 7.14.11 phy 1.45 ip=[...] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:99 memory:99000000-997fffff memory:99800000-99ffffff memory:9a030000-9a03ffff memory:95a00000-95a7ffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme II BCM57800 1/10 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       logical name: eno2
       version: 10
       serial: [...]
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bnx2x driverversion=1.712.30-0 firmware=FFV14.05.01 bc 7.14.11 phy 1.45 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:111 memory:98000000-987fffff memory:98800000-98ffffff memory:9a020000-9a02ffff memory:95a80000-95afffff
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme II BCM57800 1/10 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.2
       logical name: eno3
       version: 10
       serial: [...]
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bnx2x driverversion=1.712.30-0 duplex=full firmware=FFV14.05.01 bc 7.14.11 ip=[...] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:111 memory:97000000-977fffff memory:97800000-97ffffff memory:9a010000-9a01ffff memory:95b00000-95b7ffff
  *-network:3
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme II BCM57800 1/10 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.3
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.3
       logical name: eno4
       version: 10
       serial: [...]
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bnx2x driverversion=1.712.30-0 duplex=full firmware=FFV14.05.01 bc 7.14.11 ip=[...] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:132 memory:96000000-967fffff memory:96800000-96ffffff memory:9a000000-9a00ffff memory:95b80000-95bfffff
```

Comment: Ethtool appears to be telling you that your card doesn't support 10G. Show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Is your card installed in a PCI Express 3.0 x8 slot?

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your reply!  I just added the output and I cannot tell if its installed in an PCI Express 3.0 x8 slot.  But I can see the problem now...  I wanted 10 Gigabit Ethernet on eno3 and eno4 (eno1 is another port at 1 Gigabit).  I guess the "1/10" in the card's name doesn't mean it switches between the two...it means two ports are 1 Gbe and the other two are 10 Gbe.  And I got them flipped...  Let me reverse them and see.  (It's a vendor installed card; 1% of me was worried I was ripped off, actually...)  Thank you!

Comment: Hi!  I'd be happy to accept your answer, but it isn't quite correct.  Maybe if you correct it?  The card has 4 ports.  (This is a rack-mounted server and not a desktop.)  And two are 1 Gbe and the other two are 10 Gbe.  Your suggestion to run `sudo lshw -C network` was what led me to this.  I thought all 4 ports were the same but when I saw that output, I realised I was wrong with my assumption.  (In hindsight, if I ran `ethtool eno1`, I probably would have realised this...)

Comment: Oh, and yes, the two 10 G ports are using cat 7 cables; the single 1 G port is using a cat 6 cable.  Once I moved my cat 7 cables in eno 3 and eno 4 to eno 1 and eno 2, I got 10 G with them.  Then the cable I had at eno 1 was moved to eno 3 -- this was meant to be at 1 Gbe since it's going to a 1 Gbe switch.  (Hope I didn't lose you yet?)  But thank you!!  I did not know about `lshw`.

Comment: @heynnema By the way, can you point out where in my `lshw` output says PCI Express 3.0 x8?  I guess it must be, but for future reference, I'm curious what I should be looking at.

Comment: So does `sudo lshw -C network` now show two 10G ports, and two 1G ports? And you have two cards, each with two ports, for a total of four ports, correct? See https://www.alliedtelesis.com/sites/default/files/documents/installation-guides/brcm_nx2_server_t7-10.pdf and https://www.cnet.com/products/broadcom-netxtreme-ii-57810-network-adapter-2-ports/ and https://lenovopress.com/tips0846-broadcom-netxtreme-10gbaset

Comment: @heynnema Not quite.  It's one card with 4 ports.  The "first" two are 10 Gigabit ports; the "last" two are 1 Gigabit ports.  Yes...I tried to look for information about the specific card I have (BCM57800) and didn't find anything "useful" enough for me to understand.

Comment: @heynnema Looks good!  Is it a strange network card?  Like I said, it's a rack mounted server and well beyond what I would ever pay for myself.  It's an interesting learning experience looking after it (the server), but I sometimes get stumped.  I was recently stumped with the video display after initial installation of another server -- but on desktop computers, it always works.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Glad it's working for you. We BOTH learned something on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BCM57800 card has four ports, two ports that can operate at up to 1G speeds, and the other two ports operate at up to 10G speeds, depending on the attached cabling. Ethtool currently tells us that your cabling is not proper for 10G operation.

- the card must be in a PCI Express 3.0 x8 slot.
- for 1G operation, a cat 5e or higher cable is required.
- for 10G operation, you must use cat 6a or cat 7 cables (although minimally a cat 6 cable might work).
- for 10G operation, all network devices in the path, ie: switches, etc. must also be 10G devices.